# Throwing exception on array index

Tags: c++

I need to find a column with a greatest sum. while I am try to access arrays element shows next mistake

> exception thrown at 0x00565263 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00511048.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[101][101];
    int n, m, sum = 0, sum_max = 0, idx = 0, counter = 1;
    cin >> n >> m;      //enter size of your array

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                cin >> numbers[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; true; i++) {
            if (i == n + 1) {
                n = 1;
                counter++;
            }
            sum += numbers[i][counter];

            if (sum_max < sum) {
                sum_max = sum;
                idx = counter;
            }
        }
        cout << idx;
}
```

Comment: This loop never ends and `i` keeps on increasing, what do you think happens at `sum += numbers[i][counter];` once `i` is bigger than 100?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` - arrays are indexed from `0`, not from `1`.

Comment: Probably add some error checking for m and n values to ensure they are less than 101. Or actually use m and n to set the size of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not allocate a **fixed-size** array, and then let the user enter a **variable** amount of data. While this may "work" when respecting the maximum size, it is bound to eventually fail-by-design.
Also, it is bad for memory layout to have a partially filled array which is really an array of a smaller size with gaps in between. Your processor caches will hate you.

You should `new` the array of correct size (or use a vector which you `reserve` to `n*m`, if you will, you can still index into the buffer in two dimensions then, although that's less elegant than I like it) instead.
If it is agreeable that your program maybe runs 2% slower overall (maybe, not even necessarily!), you might create a `vector` of `vector`s. That has the immense advantage that you do not really need to know the size any more for finding the max. You can use range-based `for` or even a `std::` algorithm. Which eliminates the chance of making an out-of-index error altogether. And it *looks* much nicer.

Next, you seem to start indices at `1` for some reason (Fortran programmer?!). C++ indices start at zero.

Then, that second loop of yours has no exit condition. It will run forever, and so `counter` will eventually, no matter what size the array has, reach a value where you access an address that isn't good. At that point, you get a segmentation fault (0xC0000005). This is what you see.
Also, you seem to be doing something like (incorrect) modulo operation with a conditional branch. There exists an operator for that, which has the advantage that it also works correctly, i.e. starting the index at zero: `% n`.

Answer (score -1):

### Use an array

Use the `std::array` which is a fixed size array.

Instead of

```
int numbers[101][101];
```

use a `std::array`

```
std::array< std::array<int, 101>, 101 > numbers;
```

Now you will get better diagnostics when debugging - also you can use [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) function that will throw an exception instead of giving undefined behavior when accessing out of bounds elements.

example:

```
cin >> numbers.at(i).at(j);
```

Alternatively you might want to use a `std::vector` if you need a dynamic array.